# Unexpected Login Redirect in Localhost WordPress Sites

Tags: multisite, server, localhost, apache, network-admin

I have two WordPress websites set up for learning purposes on my `localhost`. One is a clone of the other, and both are accessible through different `loopback` addresses in my /etc/hosts file. When logging into the cloned website (duplicatetestsite.com), the login redirects me to the original website's admin panel (testsite1.com) even though they have separate databases and configurations. Before logging into the second one both are different websites. I can tell because one has an extra post.

I have `localhost` with two different hostname for different address.

The following is a part of my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       testsite1.com www.testsite1.com
127.0.0.5       duplicatetestsite.com www.duplicatetestsite.com


1. Both are installed in different folders as well as are connected to
separate databases.
2. Contents of both wp-config.php file are different.
3. Both have different virualhost file for apache server.
```

I have done the following to troubleshoot.

```
1. Verified virtual host configuration for duplicatetestsite.com.
2. Confirmed separate databases and configurations.
```

Both have different virtualhosts configured for apache.

Virtual Host Configuration:

**testsite1.com (127.0.0.1):**

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerName testsite1.com
        ServerAlias www.testsite1.com
        DocumentRoot /srv/www/wordpress
        <Directory /srv/www/wordpress>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /srv/www/wordpress/wp-content>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

**duplicatetestsite.com (127.0.0.5):**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
    ServerName duplicatetestsite.com
    ServerAlias www.duplicatetestsite3.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress3
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress3>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/wordpress3/wp-content>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I would appreciate any help regarding why this redirect is happening and how to fix it so I can log in to duplicatetestsite.com without being redirected. Additional Info This is on LAMP stack on my machine.

Initially I had posted this on superuser.com, but they suggested this is abetter fit for the problem I am facing.

Comment: Here vs superuser depends if it's WordPress that's doing the redirect or something else really. What's the blog URL and site URL on the duplicate? Are they pointing to the duplicate?

Comment: @Rup When I copy address of a post on 127.0.0.5  site it says http://127.0.0.1/index.php/2024/03/13/5-must-have-herbs-for-beginner-cooks/. How can I change 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.5 in all links?

Comment: If that's set in the blog URL and site URL in the admin dashboard, you can use any of the methods here: [Migrating WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/upgrade/migrating/). If that's saved in a saved post as HTML then you might have to search and replace in the database: I think wp-cli can do that.